# Existe alguna forma de recuperar que campos de una tabla tienen valores null?

Tags: oracle, sql, null

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE CUALQUIER CAMPO IS NULL
```

Hola, gracias por la respuesta, lo que estoy buscando es una consulta que me revise todos los campos de una tabla y me determine cual tiene registros nulos.  Por ejemplo en la tabla de la imagen, que me devuelva que los campos "Campo1" y "Campo3" tiene registros nulos.  Muchas Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es precisamente como pones en la pregunta.. algo no te funciona con eso? En ese caso podrías decirnos qué errores obtienes? Te recomiendo este enlace. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

Comment: dado que haces referencia a los `campos` entiendo que la respuesta es `no`. Lo que puedes ver es la descripción de la tabla con `DESC TABLA`, de manera que podrias ver que campos pueden admitir un valor null. Otra cosa seria que hablaramos de registros, en ese caso deberia valerte la SQL que indicas.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, amplié el detalle de la pregunta para que sea mas claro.  Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En caso de querer comprobar si una columna tiene valores nulos en alguna de sus filas como entiende el amigo @Jakala se me ocurre hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT count(col_name)>0 AS res FROM "table" WHERE col_name IS NULL
```

Si el resultado es **0** quiere decir que no hay elementos NULL en esa columna y si el resultado es **1** quiere decir que al menos hay un elemento NULL.

Eso te sirve para comprobar una columna concreta, sin embargo, para automatizar el proceso para todas las columnas de una tabla sería necesario implementar una [SQL Dinámica](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a97269/pc_13dyn.htm). En tu caso vendría a ser algo parecido a esto:

```
declare 

  mytable varchar(32) := 'MY_TABLE';

  cursor s1 (mytable varchar2) is 
            select column_name 
            from user_tab_columns
            where table_name = mytable
            and nullable = 'Y';

  mycolumn varchar2(32);
  query_str varchar2(100);    
  mycount number;

begin

  open s1 (mytable);

  loop
     fetch s1 into mycolumn; 
         exit when s1%NOTFOUND;

     query_str := 'select count(*) from ' || mytable || ' where '  || mycolumn || ' is null';

     execute immediate query_str into mycount;

     dbms_output.put_line('Column ' || mycolumn || ' has ' || mycount || ' null values');

  end loop;
end;
```

Créditos: Este ejemplo ha sido extraído de [Ejemplo SQL Dinámica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642079/query-each-column-of-a-table-in-a-loop-oracle-database)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, amplié el detalle de la pregunta para que sea mas claro.  Muchas Gracias

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta por si lo nuevo te sirve de ayuda. El ejemplo del que he copiado el código es un caso que busca exactamente lo que tú. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, es justo lo que estaba buscando. Dime como puedo ayudarte por haberme ayudado, Sds

Comment: @Damian Si consideras que la pregunta te ha sido de ayuda vota positivamente por ella (flecha ^ al principio de la respuesta). Si consideras que es la solución a tu problema márcala como tal (tick en forma de V al comienzo de la respuesta). No olvides tampoco valorar positivamente la respuesta referenciada en los créditos. Un saludo.

Comment: listo muchas gracias